# Responsive Table select dropdown cannot show all

Tags: html, css, html-table, drop-down-menu, responsive

I have a problem in the responsive table for select dropdown, it cannot view all content in the select dropdown. I have added "overflow-x:auto" in the table div to make it responsive and easy to scroll to view the table content, but just only select dropdown cannot view properly.

Below is my sample coding:

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;" id="add_files">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">File Name</th>
<th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Status</th>
<th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">File Size</th>
<th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Type</th>
<th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr id="add_fileID211125221929_95867_paneltoinsurance20211124114414" class="vpb_blue"><td><div class="filename_size" style="white-space: pre-wrap;width:100%">211125221929_22332_paneltoinsurance20211124114414.pdf</div><input type="hidden" name="doc_files_new[]" value="211125221929_22332_paneltoinsurance20211124114414.pdf"></td><td><span id="uploading_211125221929_95867_paneltoinsurance20211124114414"><span style="color:blue;">Pending</span></span></td><td>70KB</td><td style="white-space: pre-wrap;width:100%"><select class="form-control required type_doc_211125221929_95867_paneltoinsurance20211124114414" id="type_doc" name="type_doc[]" value="" title="Type" onchange="get_doc_type(this.value, '211125221929_95867_paneltoinsurance20211124114414')"><option value="5">Accident scene photos</option><option value="42">Driving License (Car owner)</option><option value="44">Driving License (Driver)</option><option value="7">Full set of police report</option><option value="3">Photocopy of Car Insurance policy</option><option value="2">Photocopy of Car registration card</option><option value="38">Photocopy of IC (Car owner)</option><option value="43">Photocopy of IC (Driver)</option><option value="37">Photocopy of SSM, form 9, form 24, form 49,</option><option value="4">Police Slip and Police report (original copy)</option></select></td><td><span id="remove211125221929_95867_paneltoinsurance20211124114414"><span class="vpb_files_remove_left_inner" onclick="vpb_remove_this_file('211125221929_95867_paneltoinsurance20211124114414','211125221929_22332_paneltoinsurance20211124114414.pdf');">Remove</span></span></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Now my result is shown like below picture:

[image: result]

I want the result can show all content properly when I scroll to view the table content like below:

[image: output6]

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

This is my whole code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RR_ko9OHJAx5PD5_3gOYwoBMePvSRk8r/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please post a working [repro] that shows the issue for debugging details.

Comment: Post some CSS, so we can help you

Comment: Please be sure to share ALL your code!

Comment: @Greenreader This is my whole code : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RR_ko9OHJAx5PD5_3gOYwoBMePvSRk8r/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Greenreader9 Thanks for helping to check this issue